# Is an array of an object stored in stack or heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

class TypeA {
 public:
  int a[10] ;
  TypeA () {
    int i ;
    for ( i = 0; i != 9; i++) {
      a[i] = double(i) ;
    }
  }
  void printVal() {
    int i ;
    for ( i = 0; i != 9; i++) {
      cout << a[i] << endl ; 
    }
  }
  ~TypeA() {
    //delete[] a;
    cout << "TypeA destructor called"<<endl;
  }

} ;


int main() {
  TypeA * ptrA = new TypeA() ;
  ptrA->printVal();
  delete ptrA ;

  return 0 ;
}
```

By `new TypeA()`, an object is instantiated on heap and a pointer is returned and kept in `main()`. I wonder if `a[]` of `TypeA` is stored on heap? If so, what is the appropriate way to free it ?

Comment: Can you explain what led you to such an impression (it's not, BTW)?

Comment: You don't need to free it - C++ puts everything into the Class'es memory .. so allocating a new TypeA gives space for the int[10] array within the memory space for the rest of class.  When you delete the Class, you are automatically freeing the memory that is used for the int[10] array.  No memory leak there at all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>
struct A{
    A() {
        std::cout<<"Called A() for "<<std::hex<<this<<'\n';
    }
};

struct B {
    A arr[10];
    B() {
        std::cout<<"Called B() for "<<std::hex<<this<<'\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    B* ptr = new B;
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<B>::value); //Sanity check for this example's case
    std::cout<<"Got ptr = "<<std::hex<<ptr<<std::dec<<" + sizeof(B)  = "<<sizeof(B)<<'\n';
    delete ptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Called A() for 0x10d4eb0
Called A() for 0x10d4eb1
Called A() for 0x10d4eb2
Called A() for 0x10d4eb3
Called A() for 0x10d4eb4
Called A() for 0x10d4eb5
Called A() for 0x10d4eb6
Called A() for 0x10d4eb7
Called A() for 0x10d4eb8
Called A() for 0x10d4eb9
Called B() for 0x10d4eb0
Got ptr = 0x10d4eb0 + sizeof(B)  = 10
```

If you see the code and the corresponding output, you can correlate that the object `ptr` of type `B` is allocated on the heap at `0x10d4eb0` and it has a size of 10 (corresponding to 10 bytes, 1 byte each for the object A). So the memory address from `0x10d4eb0` till `0x10d4eb9` is all on the heap. And if you see the address of the objects of `A`, they all fall in this address range. Hence, the objects of A do lie in the heap memory area.

Now coming to how to handle `arr`, one needs to call `delete`/`delete[]`, as the case may be, only on objects that have been allocated using `new`/`new[]`. Since that's not the case for `arr`, one doesn't need to call `delete[]` on it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally unless your class contains pointers then the entire object is contained in one allocation. As such you don't need to do anything special to clear it.

You can *only* call `delete[]` on things you've previously called `new[]` on, and it must be *exactly* the same pointer you were given. Since the `a` property was never directly instantiated, calling `delete` on it is undefined behaviour.

The way `new` works conceptually isn't that exotic, it just allocates `sizeof(X)` bytes and calls the constructor on that object. `new[]` differs only in that it allocates `sizeof(X) * N` bytes and calls the constructor `N` times.

Comment: `new[]` also stores how many objects where allocated.